# Teradata convert varchar column row values to Columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following data:

```
create volatile table current_data(
   id integer
,  rownumber integer
,  text_value varchar(10)
) on commit preserve rows;

insert into current_data values(1,1,'Text 1');
insert into current_data values(1,2,'Text 2');
insert into current_data values(1,3,'Text 3');
insert into current_data values(2,1,'Text 1');
insert into current_data values(2,2,'Text 2');
```

How can I convert the `current_data` to my `desired_data` as such?

```
create volatile table desired_data(
   id integer
,  text_value1 varchar(10)
,  text_value2 varchar(10)
,  text_value3 varchar(10)
) 
on commit preserve rows;

insert into desired_data values(1,'Text 1','Text 2','Text 3');
insert into desired_data values(2,'Text 1','Text 2',null);
```

*** Note, I would have included pictured results however I don't have proper access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when rownumber = 1 then text_value end) as text_value1,
       max(case when rownumber = 2 then text_value end) as text_value2,
       max(case when rownumber = 3 then text_value end) as text_value3
from current_data
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the [Pivot -Function of Teradata](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/GnnbigJTnAWrDfLbecAN7Q).